# Lwuit-setting ticker to labels

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I am new to j2me and i am trying to develop an application.There is a single ´Form´ and ´Form´ consists of a `Label` and a `TextBox`. I should start ticker on the `Label` depending on the screen size.please let me know how do i do it.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest solution is:

```
if (label.getPreferredW() > Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth()) {
            label.startTicker();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to force it to ticker you must use `startTicker()` method. When you want it to stop, use `stopTicker`.

In Shai´s blog, you have more info about ticker in more complex components:

http://lwuit.blogspot.com/2008/06/implementing-selected-item-ticker-in.html
http://lwuit.blogspot.com/2009/10/tickering-everywhere.html

Comment: In label, we need to start the ticker. Its not running automatically.